# how to run python script on a machine where I can't install the required package?

Tags: python, linux, python-module

I want to run a python script on a remote linux machine.
The script requires a package [networkx](https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/networkx/networkx-1.8.1-py2.7.egg#md5=ba29a8e2528114367b4fd9c4badb138b). However, I can't install python package on the remote machine, so what can I do?

Comment: Use Virtualenv and install it locally. It doesn't require any special privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are generally four options (more can exist):

## Install into user profile

```
$ pip install --user networkx
```

This does not require root priviledges and install into user specific directories.

## Install into virtualenv

```
$ virtualenv env
$ cd env
$ source bin/activate
$ pip install networkx
```

Note, there is no `--user` option present.

When you need to start the program, you will need to use python from env/bin directory, this will automatically use the virtualenv you have set up before. (no need to call `activeate`.

## Install into local subdirectory

You may put the egg or source code of needed package into local directory and manipulate sys.path to include it, then it would import from there. However, this is not easy and in fact it does the same, what virtualenv offers.

## use zc.buildout

zc.buildout tool is alternative solution to virtualenv. You can keep all in one directory tree, run from here. I used to use this solution in past many times, but comparing to virtualenv it is a bit too complex

Comment: I tried the first one, I put the .egg file for networkx in my home directory of the remote machine, but I can't install it, any more details? thanks!

Comment: BTW, I need to use `time` and `&` or even `screen` when I run the python script (which may run for a long time). if I use `virtualenv`,  will it be a problem? thanks!

Comment: @lily Installing to user profile from egg: copy the egg somewhere, cd to that directory and run: `$ pip install networkx-1.8.1-py2.7.egg`. Test it from `python` by `$ python -c "import networkx"`. If it does not complain, you got it installed. Can test it also from interactive console of ipython or python by `>>> import networkx`. The egg file you used for installation can be then removed.

Comment: @illy If a solution works in `python`, it will work in `virtualenv`

Answer (score 0):

Use [py2exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe) and [cython](http://cython.org/) to convert `.py` files to `.pyc` files..

Comment: Don't understand, can you give me more details? like procedures? thanks